# Make a phone call from UIWebView without prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

**SCENARIO**

I have an app that is a `UIWebView`, I make some url overriding for requirements.

**PROBLEM**
To make a call opening `url` with `tel:` works weird in `iOS7` and `iOS8`, it makes the phone call direct in the background, but it also ask for the confirmation, so user experience is horrible:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
```

**SOLUTION**
To solve this issue, I used `telprompt`. It works nice in all `iOS` versions:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://637****"];
return [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But shows this confirmation dialog:

[image: prompt]

**QUESTION**

Now, I have a new requirement, to make the phone call without confirmation or prompt. So... **There is some way to make a phone call in `iOS` omitting the confirmation prompt?**

I want something like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telnoprompt://637******"];
return [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: What is `HTML` code `tel:`? Just open url: `tel:....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *characterSet =[NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
NSArray *arrayOfComponents = [phone_number componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet];
phone_number = [arrayOfComponents componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phone_number];
NSString *escapedUrlString = [phoneURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
```

Comment: works like charm  @Anoop, can you please explain why? And what you did? I'm a total novice in objective C and would be pleased of learning a bit what its happening here :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla , first just make proper format for phone number which can passed in NSURL. Second, Create string formate  for phone number. Every call's URL start with "tel:" . if it's in proper formate   than you can make call.

Comment: I had to adjust your code a bit because my url is already formatted with `tel:` but direct call the phonecall request was wrong, now works perfect... why??? And why the `arrayOfComponents`?

Comment: @JordiCastilla, have you seen white space in any type of url ?

Comment: @JordiCastilla, Than you need to cast string using UTF-8. You can't direct pass string. That's what 5th line doing.